# Use numbers in every level of enumeration?

Tags: lists, enumerate

Is it possible to use only numbers on front of every item?
Something like this:

1. ABC
2. DEF

   - abc
   - def

     - xyz

But only with numbers.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use the [enumitem](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) package to define a list like the one you want; the following example is taken from the package documentation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlist{legal}{enumerate}{10}
\setlist[legal]{label*=\arabic*.}

\begin{document}

\begin{legal}
  \item First item.
  \begin{legal}
    \item First subitem.
    \begin{legal}
      \item First subsubitem.
    \end{legal}
  \end{legal}
\end{legal}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks it works, but what does the 10 in the last bracket of \newlist mean?

Comment: @thecruuk That number indicates the maximum nesting level for the created list (in standard `LaTeX` this maximum is 4). Please consider accepting the answer (by clicking the tickmark below the vote counting) that you consder solves your problem.

Comment: Ok thanks. I had to wait 7 minutes to select an answer. :)

Answer (score 8):

You can use the [`enumerate` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumerate) (although `enumitem` is far more flexible), or manage the list numbering yourself:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumerate}% http://ctan.org/pkg/enumerate
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item ABC
  \item DEF
  \begin{enumerate}[1.]
    \item abc
    \item def
    \begin{enumerate}[1.]
      \item uvw
      \item xyz
    \end{enumerate}
  \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. I was looking for just this answer. If I may add, one can change `[1.]` to `[I.]` for Latin numbering (I, II, III, ...) or, change it to `[i,]` for roman numbering (i, ii, iii, ...).